# how to get my character?

Tags: python, unicode, decode, encode

my system:xp+python27
the codec,
xp  gbk;python  27  ascii

```
>>> a = '你好'    
>>> a   
'\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'  
>>> print a  
你好  
>>> '\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'.decode('gbk')  
u'\u4f60\u597d'  
>>> '\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'.encode('gbk')   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

How can I get "你好" from '\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'  ?

Comment: can you expand on your question.language, etc?

Answer (score 6):

This works, because you're decoding bytes to unicode:

```
'\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'.decode('gbk')
```

This doesn't, because you're trying to encode bytes (which are already encoded):

```
'\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'.encode('gbk')
```

The error message in Python 2 is unhelpful here, but you should only use encode on unicode strings:

```
u'\u4f60\u597d'.encode('gbk')   # Gets you back the bytes you had before.
```

In Python 2, just doing `a` at the interactive prompt will show non-ascii characters in strings escaped (like `\xc3` or `\u4f60`). You can do `print a` to display the characters. Or use Python 3, which will display strings including the unicode characters.

Comment: @user1142618 : I think you should start by reading this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Your Python shell can't print the `gbk` encoded string. It is there, you just can't print it.

Answer (score 0):

he means that when encoding and printing it is not displaying as needed

```
>>> a = u'\u4f60\u597d'.encode('gbk')
>>> print a
���
>>> a
'\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'
```

But if specifying:

```
>>> a = '\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'
>>> print a
你好
```

You should use:

```
>>> c = '\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'.decode('gbk')
>>> c
u'\u6d63\u72b2\u30bd'
>>> c = c.encode('gbk')
>>> print c
你好
```